Error: "Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake'. Cannot find module." In Azure Function App
I am trying to deploy my script to Azure Function App. Whenever I try to trigger a function I get the error instead:
Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake'. 
Cannot find module. 
Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. 
For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound. 
Current sys.path: ['/tmp/functions\\standby\\wwwroot', '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages', 
'/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64', '/usr/local/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages'] 
Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 479, 
in _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function

My CI/CD is packaging the script in a zip file and deploying to Azure from Bitbucket:
image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  custom:
    deploy-manual:
      - step:
          name: 'Package into Zip'
          script:
            - echo 'Zipping the file'
            - cd ./AzureFunctions
            - zip -r ../func.zip .
            - cd ..
          artifacts:
            - func.zip
      - step:
          name: 'Deployment to Azure'
          script:
            - pipe: microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.2
              variables:
                AZURE_APP_ID: $
                AZURE_PASSWORD: $
                AZURE_TENANT_ID: $
                FUNCTION_APP_NAME: $
                ZIP_FILE: 'func.zip'

I do not have a file named snowflake.py or other naming conflicts.
My requirements.txt is pretty short:
azure-functions
azure-storage-blob
pandas
snowflake-connector-python
azure-identity
azure-keyvault-secrets

Function App is running functions from that file that is stored in blob storage.
I tried changing CI/CD pipeline to install requirements.txt
The zip file contained
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake_connector_python-3.11.0.dist-info/
.venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/
.venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake_connector_python-3.11.0.dist-info/
and the function was still producing the same error.
I tried changing import snowflake.connector to from snowflake import connector and update the code.
Function App is running Python 3.11 I tried switching to Python 3.9, restarting and redeploying the script but it didn't seem to work.
I can't find Function App deployment logs to see what goes wrong.
I can't find Kudu console.

If using a custom build to create the archive, you need to ensure that your dependencies are packaged in {PROJECT_ROOT}/.python_packages/lib/site-packages so that the functionapp worker can load them.
Before creating the Zip archive,

run to install dependencies in the {PROJECT_ROOT/.python_packages/lib/site-packages location.

python -m pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt


Or move the dependencies in .venv folder there.

mkdir -p .python_packages/lib
mv .venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages .python_packages/lib/site-packages

Then, create the archive without the .venv folder to keep out unnecessary files in the archive.
zip -r ../func.zip . --exclude '.venv/*'

